# How can I save my form data into the database

Tags: php, database, forms, symfony

I recently started using Symfony2 to make an easy Web App. The main functions are saving/getting data from a Data Base using forms let me add the code of the FormType and the Controller:

```
<?php
class RegistroController extends Controller{

    public function registrofamAction(){
        $peticion = $this->get('request');
        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

        $familia = new Familia();

        $familia->setRol($rol='fam');

        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(
                new FamiliaType(),
                array()
                );


        $form->setData($familia);

        if ($peticion->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bind($peticion);


            if ($form->isValid()) {

                $familia->setProgenitor1($Nombrep1);

                $em->persist($familia);
                $em->flush();
            }
        }

        return $this->render('PreditBundle:Default:registro.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }




}
?>
```

I know it would be easy but I don't have clear how the form is returned to you. Is the form in the `$peticion`? how can i manage the form info and the database?

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

The form is in the `$form` variable. When you first run the controller, you're probably in the GET mode and you construct the `$form` with a new `Familia`. 
On the second call, after doing a `POST` in the twig, you'll `bind` the request data (the `$petition`) to the `$form`, which is then validated and if everything is ok, you persist the `$familia` using doctrine entity manager.

What you have is the typical controller that is explained quite well in the symfony books:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Carefully read the symfony book http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html I know that is quite a literature to read, but it pays well since is extremely well described.

Comment: First of all thank you for your attention. I've recently found the problem. It is that it is not entering in the if ($form->isValid()). Now im trying to figure out what's wrong with the form

Comment: use the `$form->getErrors()` to get the validation errors or output them in the twig.

Comment: Yes in the end the problem was that the form I send was invalid im gonna delete this question but thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Here you get you formulaire with the request method, then the data are now in your $petition variable (you can display this var to see how it's built)

Then you 'bind' the data in your form object and if it's correct the data are persisted

Comment: First of all thank you for your attention. I've recently found the problem. It is that it is not entering in the if ($form->isValid()). Now im trying to figure out what's wrong with the form